# AWS tool Elastics alternatives

Tags: macos, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, osx-elcapitan

I use a tool called Elastics for displaying EC2 instances for AWS http://macdownload.informer.com/elastics/ but recently it is broken after installing EL Capitan and there is no support for it anymore. Is there an alternative to such tool?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE
I created an open source [AwsClient](https://github.com/gadelkareem/aws-client) if anybody is interested.

AWS Explorer seems to be the best choice http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSToolkitEclipse/latest/ug/open-aws-explorer.html

Answer (score 1):

Ideally you can install AWS CLI https://aws.amazon.com/cli/
And run something similar to this:
instanceId=`aws ec2 run-instances --image-id ami-9eaa1cf6 --count 1 --instance-type t2.micro --key-name my-key --security-group-ids $securityGroupId --subnet-id $subnetId --associate-public-ip-address --query 'Instances[0].InstanceId' --output text`